# Swipegesture on MPMoviePlayerController disturbs seeking the video in iOS 4.x

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am working on an iOS app in which I am showing the videos in MPMoviePlayerController.The user can change the video by swiping the mpmovieplayercontroller.I have managed it by using UISwipeGestureRecognizer.
All works well in iOS 5.0 but when I tried the same code on iOS 4.x then I got one issue.
Seeking the video fast causes the gesture code to run which changes the video.

How can I stop this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restricted the area on for the gesture to work on so now the swipeGesture does nothing if the touchpoint is more than a specific value so the region with seek slider doesn't get affected by the gesture.

This is just a workaround and any other more proper way is most welcome !